# How to get top rated pages in content search web part

Tags: 2013, search, content-search-web-part, cswp

Hi I'm working on Content Search Web Part in SharePoint 2013. I've configured and getting document from all site collection. Now I want to get Top rated documents in **Content Search web part**.

- For that I've enable rating in all pages library.
- I've created custom refinement and map with **ows_AverageRating** and
- added this refinement in sorting but it doesn't sort according to **Rating**.

Am I missing something?

So how to get top rated documents in Content Search Web part?

Comment: You mapped "ows_AverageRating" to managed property "RefinableDecimal00"? Did you start full crawl after that?

Comment: Hi thanks @eVT. It working now after crawling again after few time..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mapped `ows_AverageRating` to managed property `RefinableDecimal00`? Did you start full crawl after that?

Recrawl is important.